# how to make jump to code cave in Linux applications?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, x86-64, code-injection

I want to make code injection that executes some assembly language instructions for example:

```
mov eax, edx
add eax, 5
```

then returns to original code.

I know how to make jump to code cave on Windows using any language that allows me to work with memory like C or C++, if I want to make jump in x86 process I need to use `near jump`. I calculate byte representation of cave address:

```
relative offset in bytes = cave address - address of original instruction - 5;
```

`5` is length of instruction that is being replaced by JMP in bytes. Finally I add relative offset after `E9` byte to get array of 5 bytes that looks like this in assembly language: `jmp cave_address`. Then I place it in address of original instruction, CPU jumps to cave, executes cave, jumps back to address of next original instructuion.

On the other hand for x64 process I need to use `far jump`. To make far jump I create array of 14 bytes, first 6 bytes are `FF 25 00 00 00 00` and then I add cave address in its original view (without getting relative offset in bytes like I did for near jump).

So can I make jump to cave for Linux applications in the same way or I need to learn something new?

Comment: Should be the same for Linux, but what happens with the original instruction since you replaced it?

Comment: `FF 25` is not a far jump. That is an absolute indirect near jump.

Comment: @m0skit0, bytes of original instruction can be saved in variable and used to call original instruction at the end of cave like if I make hook.

Comment: Can you find 12 contiguous bytes anywhere in an executable section of the original file, like in padding between functions?  If so, you can do a 5-byte `jmp rel32` there, to code that does `mov rax, imm64` / `jmp rax`.  Or in your case, `lea eax, [rdx+5]` (3B) / `jmp rel32` (5B) to do the work and go back, only 8 bytes of total space needed.  Compilers usually default to aligning functions by 16, so you'll typically find 0 to 15 bytes of NOPs following a `ret`.  It's likely that one such location will have at least 12, and many will have 8 or more.

Comment: @PeterCordes, what if I allocate memory block of necessary size (of course if it is allowed in Linux because of in Windows I can do that using WinAPI function) and then jump to this block?

Comment: @WideWood: I thought we were talking about editing the binary.  Yeah, if you can use `ptrace` or something at run-time to have the target process make a system call to get extra memory allocated for itself (within +-2GiB of the .text section, e.g. using `MMAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE` to try a location that looks unused based on `/proc/<PID>/maps`) then you can use that.  e.g. save some code, replace it with ptrace, single-step it, then restore the original code and RIP, maybe?  I'm not sure exactly what debuggers or other things do.

Comment: AFAIK, Linux doesn't have a one-system-call equivalent for Windows functions that allocate memory inside another process.